# Which optimization algorithm does scipy.optimize.leastsq use?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares

Does anyone know which optimization algorithm specifically is implemented in scipy.optimize.leastsq?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html):

> `“leastsq”` is a wrapper around [MINPACK](http://www.netlib.org/minpack/)’s `lmdif` and `lmder` algorithms.

So (as @tillsten points out) that’s a [Levenberg–Marquardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) implementation.

Comment: Which is a Levenberg-Marquard implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!  I've added it to the answer.